# password define for ssh connection into docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ssh, docker-machine

I would like to connect with SSH into my docker container. For that I created image with this Dockerfile and this command `docker build -t test/toto .` :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.4
MAINTAINER Darkomen <darkomen@xxx.com>

# Let the conatiner know that there is no tty
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN sudo apt-get -y update

RUN sudo apt-get -y install software-properties-common python-software-properties
RUN sudo add-apt-repository main
RUN sudo add-apt-repository universe
RUN sudo add-apt-repository restricted
RUN sudo add-apt-repository multiverse

RUN sudo apt-get -y update

#RUN sudo apt-get -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
RUN sudo apt-get -y install linux-headers-generic build-essential
RUN apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-gplv2-dev
RUN apt-get -y install curl unzip
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN apt-get -y install gnupg2

# others tools
RUN sudo apt-get -y install nano
RUN sudo apt-get -y install vim
RUN sudo apt-get -y install aptitude
RUN sudo apt-get -y install git
RUN sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jdk
RUN sudo apt-get -y install whois
RUN sudo apt-get -y install dos2unix

# SSH
RUN apt-get -y install openssh-server
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' |chpasswd

EXPOSE 22
CMD    /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

next I launched my container with this image with this command : `docker run test/toto -p 42000:22`

My container run perfectly and I launch this command for enter into this container : `docker run -dt -p 42000:22 test/toto`

Now my docker-machine and docker container (based on my dockerfile) run. I can view that because `docker ps -a` tell me that :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                   NAMES
a28ad08fd393        test/toto           "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbi"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes                 0.0.0.0:42000->22/tcp   admiring_feynman
```

For connecting in my container I launch this command : `ssh root@192.168.99.100 -p 42000`

*But it tell me to enter a password. I try lot of thing but nothing run. What I do forget in my process of creation and configuration docker ?*

192.168.99.100 is the IP return by the `docker-machine inspect` command

I also tried to change root password into my container and repeat ssh command access. But nothing change. I can't connecting to container.

**technical information:**

- OS : windows 7 Pro
- Docker version : 1.12.2 build bb80604
- Docker system : docker toolbox (based on VirtualBox)
- VirtualBox version : 5.0.14r105127

Comment: Does `docker run` work?

Comment: Well, probably forgot to set up `root` password?

Comment: My docker run, run perfectly. I already set up root password in Dockerfile but perhaps you have more best solution...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to configure root login for your sshd:

Manual:

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Change `PermitRootLogin without-password` to:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Then:

```
service ssh restart
```

Now try again. If everything went fine, you need to change your docker file to make this change in the build steps.

Comment: ```service ssh restart``` generate a exit from container and stop it. I can't try this trick.

Comment: do it in your docker file then, via copy instruction, before starting ssh service.

Answer (score 8):

Dockerfile script for create and expose a SSH connection into container :

```
# SSH
RUN apt-get -y install openssh-server
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

# authorize SSH connection with root account
RUN sed -i '/^#/!s/PermitRootLogin .*/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sudo service ssh restart

# change password root
RUN echo "root:docker"|chpasswd
```

Comment: No sudo in a Dockerfile, Dockerfile always uses sudo.